# Find the diff. eq. whose solution is given by...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have recently started to self-study the book "Ordinary Differential Equations" by M. Tenenbaum and H. Pollard. I have no previous knowledge in diff. eq. but I am pretty solid in the calculus of one variable. I have trouble with a problem which I hope you can show me how to solve. The problem is as follows:
Find the diff. eq. whose solution is given by the 1-parameter family of solutions:
$$ r=\theta*tan(\theta + c)$$
The answer is: $$\theta r' = \theta ^2 + r^2 +r$$
So if somebody could show me how to get to the above diff. eq. given the function $r(\theta)$ , it would be highly appreciated.

P.S this is my first post on the site, so I hope I've proceeded as I should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 
$$
r=\theta \tan (\theta+c)
$$
we have
$$
\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\tan(\theta +c)+\theta\left[1+\tan^2(\theta+c)\right]
$$
so, multiplying by $\theta$:

$$
\theta r'=\theta\tan(\theta +c)+\theta^2\left[1+\tan^2(\theta+c)\right]
$$
and substituting $\theta \tan (\theta+c)=r$ you find your differential equation.

---

product rule:
$$
\frac{d}{d \theta}(\theta \tan (\theta+c))=1\cdot \tan (\theta+c)+\theta \frac{d}{d \theta}(\tan (\theta+c))=
$$
derivative of $\tan x$
$$
=\tan (\theta+c)+\theta \frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta +c)}=
$$
$1=\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x$:
$$
=\tan (\theta+c)+\theta \frac{\cos^2(\theta+c)+\sin^2(\theta+c)}{\cos^2(\theta +c)}=
$$
$\tan x= \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$:
$$
=\tan(\theta +c)+\theta\left[1+\tan^2(\theta+c)\right]
$$

Comment: Isn't the derivative wrong? I very much appreciate your help, though.

Comment: What  is wrong?  I'don't see......

Comment: if $r(\theta)=\theta*tan(\theta + c)$ then
$$\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \frac{sin(\theta + c)*cos(\theta + c) + \theta}{cos(\theta + c)^2}$$

Comment: Perhaps I have missed some simplification?

Comment: I don't understand your derivative... I've added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It is perfectly clear now :-)

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to note that
$$
\left(-\theta+\arctan\frac r\theta\right)'=0,
$$
which gives
$$
-1+\left(\frac r\theta\right)'\frac1{1+r^2/\theta^2}=\frac{-1-r^2/\theta^2+r'/\theta-r/\theta^2}{1+r^2/\theta^2}=0.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\theta r'=\theta^2+r^2+r.
$$